# Multithreaded MSMQ Listening

Tags: c#, msmq

I'm currently reading from my MSMQ like so (simplified for brevity):

```
public void Start()
{
    this.queue.ReceiveCompleted += this.ReceiveCompleted;
    this.queue.BeginReceive();
}

void ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
            
    try
    {
        var m = e.Message;
        m.Formatter = this.formatter;

        this.Handle(m.Body);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.queue.BeginReceive();
    }
}
```

However this only allows me to process messages in serial. How do I modify this code to allow parallel message processing?

I know I can move the `this.queue.BeginReceive();` out of the `finally` and into the top of the `ReceiveCompleted` but whats to stop that spawning as many threads as I have messages? How do I sensibly control the level of parallelism so I don't flood the threadpool? Is there some inbuilt mechanism for this, or do I have to write my own manager?

### Edit

My aim is to process messages faster. The processing of the messages involves an async call to a third party, so currently my implementation is wasting a lot of time in getting through the queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be simpler to just host more instances of your queue reader. Then you can quickly scale up and down depending on need by deploying/undeploying more instances.

Also it becomes a management, rather than a development concern, which is what scaling should be.

Comment: I hoped this was the case, would that guarantee that a message only gets processed once? or is there a chance that two listeners could receive the same message?

Comment: What I should have added is that you can only guarantee that by using transactional queues. I can't find it in the docs, however I have set up this scaling mechanism before, and also the WCF integration with msmq provides a property called exactly once which would imply that this is a feature of msmq.

Comment: My queue is transactional, is there anything special I need to do, or should that just work(tm)?

Comment: @Hugh, what can you only guarantee by using transactional queues? That a message is only read once?

Comment: @John yes - that is my understanding.

Comment: The MSMQ service will only allow a message to be read once. A message can be peeked as many times as you like but a receive call will effectively make the message disappear. This isn't a function specific to TX queues. I don't know what the WCF property does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "Producer Consumer Pattern"...

.NET 4 and up has `Concurrent` collections which are thread-safe and implemented "mostly lock-free" (thus perform well with multi-threading)...

You could use [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) combined with TPL to achieve what you want without much worry of threadpool starvation or similar... you would only change the line `this.Handle(m.Body);`  to something like `MyBlockingCollection.Add(m.Body);` and spin up "consumer threads" which work on `MyBlockingCollection` and do the actual work (i.e. call `this.Handle` on the next item from `MyBlockingCollection` which they get by calling `TryTake` for example) ... see the above link for a basic sample...

Comment: that sounds like im just making a non-persisted in-memory queue on the end of my queue :/

Comment: If I have multiple instances of the above code listening to the same queue, does MSMQ quarantee atomic popping, so a message is only processed by one listener?

Comment: @AndrewBullock basically that is a non-persisted thread-safe in-memory-queue which can be consumed by multiple threads in parallel...

Comment: In answer to your question, yes msmq guarantees "atomic popping".

Comment: @hugh thanks, do you know where this is described in the docs? (not that i dont trust you ;) just cant find it)

Comment: @AndrewBullock MSMQ supports multiple readers, use more threads or more processes